# How to delete rows from database using HTML option tag and delete button?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Just like the title above I am trying to delete a row in a database using a button and a drop down, I have already made it so that you can select the ID in the drop down list which refers to the sql database, but I dont know where to start coding in which I want the user to select an ID from a drop down and then click the delete button to safely remove that referred row. help??

```
       procedure ALFRED_DELETE

        IS

        CURSOR selectcursor 
         IS
          SELECT empid
          FROM alfred_form_table;

        BEGIN


        --CSS and Title
        htp.p ('

        <html>


        <p width = 100% align="left">

              <form name ="deleteForm" action="alfred_first_package.Delete_Button" method="post" >    

             <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" summary="">   

                 <tr>
                    <H3>Delete Information</h3>
                 </tr>

                 <P> Please select an Empoyee ID to Delete from the database!!!</p>  


                 <select> ');

                 for i in ( SELECT empid
                             FROM alfred_form_table)
                             loop

                htp.p(' 
                <option style="width:50" value="'||i.empid||'">'||i.empid||'  </option>');

                end loop; 
                htp.p('
                </select>

                   </table>

                 <br> 
                   <input type ="submit"  name="DeleteInfo" value="Delete Information" align="right" />

               </form>

            </table>

        </html>
         ');
        end ALFRED_DELETE;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    PROCEDURE Delete_Button(DeleteInfo in varchar2)
    IS
    BEGIN
    null;
    /*
    htp.p('<html>
    <body>

     <p> You have deleted added '||EID||', '||JamesbondID||', and '||ENAME||' from the database! </p> 

    </body>
    </html>

    ');

    */
    end Delete_button;
```

Comment: you're building html in sql? since when is an sql server an http server as well?

Comment: I am using Notepad to code, and SQL Plus as a compiler.